# Posting Search results in a Table Assistance Needed

Tags: php, sql, search

I would like to display the results of this search in a table, would anyone be able to tell me how I could achieve such a thing please? I got this code from a tutorial website but alas it does not tell me how to get my results in a four column table. Such as this layout.

---

|Picture|Name|Description|Price|

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "catalog");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

error_reporting(0);

$output = '';

if(isset($_GET['q']) && $_GET['q'] !== ' '){
    $searchq = $_GET['q'];

    $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM final_dog_catologue_full WHERE name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR brand LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die(mysqli_error());
    $c = mysqli_num_rows($q);
    if($c == 0){
        $output = 'No search results for <b>"' . $searchq . '"</b>';
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){
            $Name = $row['Name'];
            $brand = $row['Brand'];
            $picture = $row['Picture'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $Retail_Price_With_Delievery = $row['Price'];

            $output .= '<a href="' . $brand . '">
                        <h3>' . $brand . '</h3>
                            <p>'. $brand .'</p>
                        </a>';
        }
    }
} else {
    header("location: ./");
}
print("$output");
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.  It's pretty clear you haven't really tried anything to get it into a table.

Comment: That's part of the problem, I'm new to coding and have very little idea of where to start...

Comment: Start by Googling [html table](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tables.htm), and fiddle with your code with what you see there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To display the values into a table using HTML, just modify the $output variable

```
$output .= '<tr>
               <td>' . $picture. '</td>
               <td>' . $name . '</td>
               <td>'. $description .'</td>
               <td>'. $price .'</td>
            </tr>';
```

You would need to add the "table" tags before and after while loop

```
else {
$output = '<table><tr>
             <th>' . $picture. '</th>
             <th>' . $name . '</th>
             <th>'. $description .'</th>
             <th>'. $price .'</th>
           </tr>';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)){...}
$output .= '</table>';
```